# EF 4.1 skip dictionary tables for member collection

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

It's a little bit hard to find an appropriate title for this.
I think it's a basic issue, but I can't find the solution.

```
public class Car
{
  ...
  public ICollection<Parts> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Parts
{
  ...
}
```

The application has a "repository" or "catalog" for parts.
When I edit a car entity I can choose from this repository to add a part.

I have two problems with the default mapping:

1. I want to able to delete a part a from the catalog without deleting it from
   the car.
2. If I add a part only to a car manually, it will appear in the "catalog" which shouldn't.

In other words I want separate Parts db tables:
 1. For the parts which related to specific cars (Parts (collection) member of Car class)
 2. For the catalog to choose from

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to the Parts entity called "ShowInCatalog" and set it to 0 for the ones you don't want to show up in your catalog (thus the catalog will do a query to get everything with that value at 1).

Comment: thanks for the response.
Ok it's obvious, but it goes against the code first approach.
I want to keep on minimum the modifications made on the model because of persistence. And I don't want to implement any persistence related business logic into my model.
I can think of some kind of mapping which will tell EF that store car related parts collection members in a table "CarParts" and store stand alone instances of Part in table "Parts".  
  
If we think this over from object oriented perspective it's trivial in my opinion that a collection members are different entities than an other

Comment: collection members they just share a common structure (type)

Comment: @Sandor It does, but it's good SQL table design. Abstractions are always leaky in some way, and what you're proposing to do instead is going to create a lot of extra complexity elsewhere for no gain except "code first approach purity". A Part is a Part, they're the same thing no matter if they're in a car or not. Thus it's one entity. That also avoids duplication. With two of them, if you take a Part and put it in a Car (while still in the catalog) you now have two entries for the same part. It's just not a good idea.